# Pass data correctly to another dust template

Tags: html, dust.js

There is a base.tl which contains two columns like below:

```
<li class="column region">
  {@partial placeholder = "region" id="column-region" }
    {> "templates/partials/column" /}
  {/partial}
</li>

<li class="column industry">
  {@partial placeholder = "industry" id="column-industry" }
    {> "templates/partials/column" /}
  {/partial}
</li>
```

This is the column.tl which contains a input box. I want one of them is readonly and the other is not. So I add readOnly like this.
But I do not know how to parse the boolean readOnly from the base.tl to here.

```
<div class="column-content">
  <input placeholder="{placeholder}"
    class="add-preference-input"
    type="text" {?readOnly}readonly{/readOnly} />
</div>
```

Seems like I parse the param like placeholder but it cannot tell it is a boolean. How do I parse a boolean to the partial template and let it be recognized? Is it possible or I have to use javescript to help it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that Dust cannot pass booleans directly as params-- they'll just be stringified.

However, the `{?exists}` tag checks for existence, not truthiness. So you have several options.

**Instead of passing true and false, pass "true" and "" (empty string)**

```
{@partial placeholder="region" readonly="" id="column-region"}
```

**Use the `{@eq}` helper from dustjs-helpers**

```
{@eq key="readonly" value="true" type="boolean"}readonly{/eq}
```

**Put variables in your context that are equal to `true` and `false`**

```
{@partial placeholder="region" readonly=FalseContextVar}
```